# Teraterm Sendln issue, it cannot send the full command

Tags: teraterm

I need help when debugging teraterm script. The simple codes shown below:

```
connect "/c=20 /baud=115200"
pause(8)
cmd = 'r 10314 1'
sendln cmd 
pause(3)
closet
```

Actually only send command of `"r 10314 1"`. What I saw that this command is issued successfully, but in Teraterm window, only the command shows: `r 1` . Why `sendln` doesn't send all the commands? Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that both devices can handle that fast of a baud rate? Instead of 115200, have you tried a slower speed?

The code looks good (as in you are only sending one string with the same apostrophe on both sides, this can also be achieved with two double quotes) and waiting 3 seconds after, there should be no problem; **I would try with lower baud rates to see if you aren't trying to send the data faster than capable.**

Here's some things to look at that can maybe help:
https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/syntax/formats.html
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-communication/all

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried to change the baud rate with "9600" shown below. However at the first setting I must set the speed of "115200", or it cannot work well. And the issue still is the same. Appreciate the further suggestion.

connect "/c=20 /baud=115200"
pause(8)
setbaud(7)
cmd = 'r 10314 1'
sendln 'r 10314 1'
pause(3)

Thanks so much!